# SQL Query to Update Object Count Based on Event Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, qsqlquery

Imagine I am an owner of many bookstores. I keep a database of all events that occur in all of my many bookstores. Two events of note are "Book Added" and "Book Removed", for when a book is added to the inventory of a story, and when it is sold from a store. An example schema would be `bookstore_id`, `event_name`, `time.

Now say I have a second table, which maintains the current state of each bookstore, so the schema would be `bookstore_id`, `num_books`.

I want to be able to use the first table to get the count of all the "Book Added" events per bookstore, subtract the count of all the "Book Removed" events per bookstore, and then update the number of books in each bookstore in the second table.

The only way I can think to do it requires using a cursor, but I'm assuming there's a more "SQL-esque" way to do it that is more set-based and doesn't require a cursor.

Comment: After an update do you delete all of the event rows so that you can handle the next batch of transactions, or do you keep track of the ones that have already been used to adjust the counts?

Answer (score 1):

```
select bookstore_id
     , sum(case when event_name = "Book Removed" then -1 else 1 end) as "num books"
  from bookstores  
 group by bookstore_id
```

if more than 2 events

```
select bookstore_id
     , sum(case when event_name = "Book Removed" then -1 
                when event_name = "Book Added"   then  1  
           end) as "num books"
  from bookstores  
 group by bookstore_id
```

And I would just make it a view unless you come up with performance issues

Comment: I think there are more than just these two events in the table. And of course you've left out the `end`

Answer (score 1):

You can count the events by using a `GROUP BY` clause.

If we would create 2 subtables where we count the added respectively the removed books, we can simply subtract the results and update these in the parent table. This will look like:

```
UPDATE      b
SET         b.numbooks = AddedBooks.BooksAdded - RemovedBooks.BooksRemoved
FROM        dbo.Books b
INNER JOIN  (SELECT     be.book_id, count(*) AS BooksAdded
            FROM        dbo.BookEvents be
            WHERE       be.event = 'BookAdded'
            GROUP BY    be.book_id, be.event) AS AddedBooks 
                                    ON b.bookid = AddedBooks.book_id
INNER JOIN  (SELECT     be.book_id, count(*) AS BooksRemoved
            FROM        dbo.BookEvents be
            WHERE       be.event = 'BookRemoved'
            GROUP BY    be.book_id, be.event) AS RemovedBooks  
                                    ON b.bookid = RemovedBooks.book_id
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use CTEs to get details individually and process them.

```
With CTE_Add AS
(
Select Bkstr_ID, Count(event_Name) As Added From temp Where event = 'Added' Group by Bkstr_ID
), CTE_Rem As
(
Select Bkstr_ID, Count(event_Name) As Removed From temp Where event = 'Removed'      Group by Bkstr_ID
)
Select A.Bkstr_ID,  Added - Removed
From CTE_Add A
Left Join CTE_Rem R On A.Bkstr_ID= R.Bkstr_ID
```

This will give you ID and count.
Instead of select, you can use Insert statement

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `SUM(CASE WHEN ...)`. Below is an example.

```
If object_id('tempdb..#BoookStores') Is Not Null Drop Table #BoookStores
Create Table #BoookStores (bookstore_id int, num_books int)

/* We have 3 stores */
Insert #BoookStores (bookstore_id, num_books)
Values  (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)

If object_id('tempdb..#Events') Is Not Null Drop Table #Events
Create Table #Events (bookstore_id int, event_name varchar(10), time dateTime Default(GetDate()) )

Insert #Events (bookstore_id, event_name)
Values
(1, 'Added'), (1, 'Added'), (1, 'Added'), (1, 'Added'), -- Added 4 books to 1. store
(2, 'Added'), (2, 'Added'), (2, 'Added'), -- Added 3 books to 2. store
(3, 'Added'), (3, 'Added'), -- Added 2 books to 3. store

/* removed 2 books from each stores */
(1, 'Removed'), (1, 'Removed'), 
(2, 'Removed'), (2, 'Removed'),
(3, 'Removed'), (3, 'Removed')

/* Calculate adds and removes. Update the results */
;With Tmp As (
    Select  E.bookstore_id,
            Sum(Case When E.event_name = 'Added' Then 1 Else 0 End) As AddCount,
            Sum(Case When E.event_name = 'Removed' Then 1 Else 0 End) As RemoveCount
    From    #Events E
    Group By E.bookstore_id
)
Update  BS Set num_books = T.AddCount-T.RemoveCount
From    #BoookStores BS
        Inner Join Tmp T On T.bookstore_id = BS.bookstore_id 

/* check results*/
Select * From #BoookStores BS
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will get you in the ball park. Similar logic could be used for INSERT.

```
UPDATE tableA
SET tableA.num_books = tableB.num_books
FROM secondTable AS TableA
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT bookstore_id,
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN event_name = 'Books Added'
                    THEN 1
                END) - SUM(CASE 
                WHEN event_name = 'Books Removed'
                    THEN 1
                END
            ) AS num_books
    FROM firstTable
    GROUP BY bookstore_id
    ) TableB ON TableA.bookstore_id = tableB.bookstore_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a query like below:

```
update t1
set num_books=inventory
FROM bs t1 LEFT JOIN
(select bookstore_id,SUM(case when event_name like 'A' then 1 when event_name like 'R' then -1 else NULL end)  as inventory
from bse 
group by bookstore_id) t2
on t1.bookstore_id=t2.bookstore_id
```

[**Live SQL demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67776d/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  bsc
SET     bsc.num_books = bse.num_books
FROM    bookstorecounts bsc
        JOIN (SELECT    bookstore_id,
                        SUM(CASE event_name
                              WHEN 'Book Removed' THEN -1
                              WHEN 'Book Added' THEN 1
                            END) AS num_books
              FROM      bookstoreevents
              GROUP BY  bookstore_id
        ) bse ON bsc.bookstore_id = bse.bookstore_id
```